# How to change the order of arguments?

Tags: haskell

What if I want to change the order of arguments in a function?

There is `flip`:

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

but I don't see how to make it work for a larger number of arguments. Is there a general method to permute the arguments?

Comment: @phimuemue it may be not a function, but TH macros. Yes, such macro can be written, but simple lambda is almost as short.

Comment: If you tend to have a lot of arguments, you might miss opportunities to create appropriate data types. Or you're just a querulous person.

Answer (score 41):

If you feel like editing functions after they're written, you really really should read 
Conal Elliott's excellent blog post *semantic editor combinators*

http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators

In fact, everyone should read it anyway. It's a genuinely useful
method (which I'm abusing here). Conal uses more constructs than just `result` and `flip` to very flexible effect.

```
result :: (b -> b') -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> b'))
result =  (.)
```

Suppose I have a function that uses 3 arguments

```
use3 :: Char -> Double -> Int -> String
use3 c d i = c: show (d^i)
```

and I'd like to swap the first two, I'd just use `flip use3` as you say,
but if I wanted to swap the seconnd and third, what I want is to apply `flip` 
to the result of applying `use3` to its first argument.

```
use3' :: Char -> Int -> Double -> String
use3' = (result) flip use3
```

Let's move along and swap the fourth and fifth arguments of a function `use5` that uses 5.

```
use5  :: Char -> Double -> Int -> (Int,Char) -> String     -> String
use5' :: Char -> Double -> Int -> String     -> (Int,Char) -> String

use5 c d i (n,c') s = c : show (d ^ i) ++ replicate n c' ++ s
```

We need to apply `flip` to the result of applying `use5` to it's first three arguments,
so that's the result of the result of the result:

```
use5' = (result.result.result) flip use5
```

Why not save thinking later and define

```
swap_1_2 :: (a1 -> a2 -> other) -> (a2 -> a1 -> other)
swap_2_3 :: (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> other) -> (a1 -> a3 -> a2 -> other)
--skip a few type signatures and daydream about scrap-your-boilerplate and Template Haskell    

swap_1_2 = flip    
swap_2_3 = result flip
swap_3_4 = (result.result) flip
swap_4_5 = (result.result.result) flip
swap_5_6 = (result.result.result.result) flip
```

...and that's where you should stop if you like simplicity and elegance. 
Note that the type `other` could be `b -> c -> d` so because of fabulous Curry and right associativity of `->`, 
swap_2_3 works for a function which takes any number of arguments above two.
For anything more complicated, you should really write a permuted function by hand.
What follows is just for the sake of intellectual curiosity.

Now, what about swapping the second and fourth arguments?
[Aside: there's a theorem I remember from my algebra lectures 
that any permutation can be made as the composition of swapping adjacent items.]

We could do it like this:
step 1: move 2 next to 4 (`swap_2_3`)

```
a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> otherstuff
a1 -> a3 -> a2 -> a4 -> otherstuff
```

swap them there using `swap_3_4`

```
a1 -> a3 -> a2 -> a4 -> otherstuff
a1 -> a3 -> a4 -> a2 -> otherstuff
```

then swap 4 back to position 2 using `swap_2_3` again:

```
a1 -> a3 -> a4 -> a2 -> otherstuff
a1 -> a4 -> a3 -> a2 -> otherstuff
```

so

```
swap_2_4 = swap_2_3.swap_3_4.swap_2_3
```

Maybe there's a more terse way of getting there directly with lots of results 
and flips but random messing didn't find it for me!

Similarly, to swap 1 and 5 we can move 1 over to 4, swap with 5, move 5 back from 4 to 1.

```
swap_1_5 = swap_1_2.swap_2_3.swap_3_4 . swap_4_5 . swap_3_4.swap_2_3.swap_1_2
```

Or if you prefer you could reuse `swap_2_4` by flipping at the ends 
(swapping 1 with 2 and 5 with 4), swap_2_4 then flipping at the ends again.

```
swap_1_5' = swap_1_2.swap_4_5. swap_2_4 .swap_4_5.swap_1_2
```

Of course it's much easier to define

```
swap_1_5'' f  a b c d e = f  e b c d a
```

which has the benefit of being clear, consise, efficient and has a helpful type signature in ghci without explicitly annotating it.

However, this was a fantastically entertaining question, thanks.

Comment: Or, for the less sane, `swap_5_6 = ((((flip.).).).)` and `swap_2_4 = (flip.).((flip.).).(flip.)`.

Answer (score 12):

The best way in general is to just do it manually. Assume you have a function

```
f :: Arg1 -> Arg2 -> Arg3 -> Arg4 -> Res
```

and you would like

```
g :: Arg4 -> Arg1 -> Arg3 -> Arg2 -> Res
```

then you write

```
g x4 x1 x3 x2 = f x1 x2 x3 x4
```

If you need a particular permutation several times, then you can of course abstract from it, like `flip` does for the two-argument case:

```
myflip :: (a4 -> a1 -> a3 -> a2 -> r) -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> r
myflip f x4 x1 x3 x2 = f x1 x2 x3 x4
```

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it, if you need a specialized rearrangement of arguments it's easiest to define your own function to do it, but I suspect any of these can be generated with compositions of flip, and lambdas like (\x -> flip $ f x) that partially apply the function to flip around arguments other than the first and second.