# Can I create my own function composition operator in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

The function composition operator in Haskell is defined as:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

When I try to create my own function composition operator, `o` in Haskell, it does not work, what am I doing wrong?

```
o :: a -> (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> c

g :: Double -> String
g x = show x 

h :: Int -> Double
h x = fromIntegral x

f :: Int -> String
f x = o x h g       -- can it also be written like this: f = o h g
```

**Error message:**

```
C:\Users\August\Desktop\Haskell\Template\Ex.hs:36:1: error:
    The type signature for `o' lacks an accompanying binding
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: It doesn’t work for exactly the reason the error message says: you wrote a type signature for `o` but didn’t write a definition such as `o x f g = g (f x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `o` is very similar to function composition `.`:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

you could rewrite the definition of `.` and just slightly rearrange the arguments:

```
o :: a -> (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> c
o x f g = g (f x)
```

or you could try to create `o` by shuffling around the arguments of `.`:

```
o = (flip .) . flip . (flip .) $ (.)
```

In this definition, we are using `flip` to swap the first and second argument of `(.)` and `(flip .)` to swap the second and third argument. For a function `a -> b -> c -> d` that would give us:

```
a -> b -> c -> d
-- swap b and c with (flip .)
a -> c -> b -> ->d
-- swap a and c with (.)
c -> a -> b -> -> d
-- swap a and b
c -> b -> a -> d with (flip .)
```

If you're wondering why `(flip .)` swaps the second and third argument, I recommend you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131896/3684713) and [the blog post that was linked in it](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators). it boils down to `.` making sure that `flip` gets applied to the result of whatever function you pass to `(flip .)` and swapping the first and second argument of the result of a function is the same as swapping its second and third argument.

---

To be perfectly honest though, I don't see the need for your `o` function since you could just rewrite `f` as:

```
 f :: Int -> String
 f x = g . h $ x
```

or even

```
f = g . h
```